# Pdfsharp Out of Memory Exception when Combine Multi Pdf File

Tags: c#, pdf, exception, pdfsharp

I have to convert into a single pdf a large number (but undefined) pdf into one for this, I'm using the code PDFsharp here.

```
    // Get some file names
    string[] files = filesToPrint.ToArray();

    // Open the output document
    PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

    PdfPage newPage; 

    int nProcessedFile = 0;
    int nMemoryFile = 5;
    int nStepConverted = 0;
    String sNameLastCombineFile = ""; 


    // Iterate files
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        // Open the document to import pages from it.
        PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        // Iterate pages
        int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
        {
            // Get the page from the external document...
            PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
            // ...and add it to the output document.
            outputDocument.AddPage(page);                                
        }

        nProcessedFile++;
        if (nProcessedFile >= nMemoryFile)
        {
            //nProcessedFile = 0;
            //nStepConverted++;
            //sNameLastCombineFile = "ConcatenatedDocument" + nStepConverted.ToString() + " _tempfile.pdf";

            //outputDocument.Save(sNameLastCombineFile);
            //outputDocument.Close();                 
        }
    }
    // Save the document...
    const string filename = "ConcatenatedDocument1_tempfile.pdf";
    outputDocument.Save(filename);
    // ...and start a viewer.
   Process.Start(filename);
```

For small numbers of files the code works but then at some point
generates an exception of out of memory

is there a solution?

p.s
I was thinking of saving the files in step and then the remaining aggiungingere so liebrare memory but I can not find the way.

UPDATE1:

```
if (nProcessedFile >= nMemoryFile)
{
nProcessedFile = 0;
//nStepConverted++;
sNameLastCombineFile = "ConcatenatedDocument" + nStepConverted.ToString() + " _tempfile.pdf";

outputDocument.Save(sNameLastCombineFile);
outputDocument.Close();

outputDocument = PdfReader.Open(sNameLastCombineFile,PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
}
```

UPDATE 2 versione 1.32
Complete example 
Error on line:
**PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);**

Text error:
**Cannot handle iref streams. The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6.**

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> filesToPrint = new List<string>();

            filesToPrint = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Downloads\RACCOLTA\FILE PDF", "*.pdf").ToList();

            // Get some file names
            string[] files = filesToPrint.ToArray();

            // Open the output document
            PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

            PdfPage newPage;

            int nProcessedFile = 0;
            int nMemoryFile = 5;
            int nStepConverted = 0;
            String sNameLastCombineFile = "";

            try
            {
                // Iterate files
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    // Open the document to import pages from it.
                    PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

                    // Iterate pages
                    int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
                    {
                        // Get the page from the external document...
                        PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
                        // ...and add it to the output document.
                        outputDocument.AddPage(page);
                    }

                    nProcessedFile++;
                    if (nProcessedFile >= nMemoryFile)
                    {
                        nProcessedFile = 0;
                        //nStepConverted++;
                        sNameLastCombineFile = "ConcatenatedDocument" + nStepConverted.ToString() + " _tempfile.pdf";

                        outputDocument.Save(sNameLastCombineFile);
                        outputDocument.Close();

                        inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(sNameLastCombineFile , PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
                    }
                }
                // Save the document...
                const string filename = "ConcatenatedDocument1_tempfile.pdf";
                outputDocument.Save(filename);
                // ...and start a viewer.
                Process.Start(filename);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE3
Code that generate exception out of memory

```
            int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
            {
                // Get the page from the external document...
                newPage = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
                // ...and add it to the output document.
                outputDocument.AddPage(newPage);

                newPage.Close();
            }
```

I can not exactly which row general exception

Comment: The message "Cannot handle iref streams" means you have to use PDFsharp 1.50 Prerelease, available on NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

I had a simular issue, saving, closing and reopening the PdfDocument did not really help.

I am adding al lot (100+) large (upto 5Mb) images (tiff, jpg, etc) to a pdf document where every images has its own page. It crashed around image #50. After the save-close-reopen it did finish the whole document but was still getting close to max memory, around 3Gb. Some more images and it would still crash.

After more refining, I implemented a using for the XGraphics object, it was a little better again but not much.

The big step forward was disposing of the XImage within the loop! After that the application never used more than 100-200Kb, I removed the save-close-reopen for the PdfDocument and it was no problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, have been sick for a while.

Comment: using (XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage))
            {
                // ... Code ...

                // Image
                image = XImage.FromFile(file.FullName);

                // ... More code ...

                gfx.DrawImage(image, mPositionX, mPositionY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                image.Dispose();

                // ... Even more code ...
            }

Answer (score 0):

After saving and closing `outputDocument` (the code is commented out in your snippet), you have to open `outputDocument` again, using `PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify`.

It could help to add `using(...)` for the `inputDocument`.

If your code is running as a 32-bit process, then switching to 64 bit will allow your process to use more than 2 GB of RAM (assuming your computer has more than 2 GB RAM).

Update: The message "Cannot handle iref streams" means you have to use PDFsharp 1.50 Prerelease, available on NuGet.

Comment: I tried this code but the error occurs, 
see update1

Comment: "Yes" is no useful answer to the question "Which error occurs?"  Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: in practice the same exception was thinking if it was appropriate to make a few calls dispose ?

Comment: sorry for the delay but I was sick. 
I'm trying different solution but so far I have not found anything to help me.

Comment: We are in no hurry. You do not provide an MCVE, you do not provide a stack trace, you do not provide detailed error information, so there is not much we can do for you now.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: with update 2 super that error message but on a different pdf from this:
Token 'endobj' was not expected.

Comment: in some cases some pdf (containing images) are concatenated with broken images rev 1.50 gdi

Comment: The exception System.OutOfMemoryException raise 
see update3

Comment: If you have problems with unexpected tokens, broken images, or out of memory exceptions then please submit the PDF files that cause these problems so we can fix the problems in PDFsharp. Your code snippets do not help us locating the problem. A stack trace might help, but the best case is having the PDF file to replicate the problem in the debugger.

Comment: The situations that occur are:
1. out of memory
2. broken image
3. Tokens 'endobj' (but lets leave this aside)
4. from pages 40 and following blank sheet error when open with acrobat
I do not know if I can put the pdf I try to check the stack

Comment: maybe the problem is generated when creating new doc
He did not have time to make the flush of data (being great) and then resume queuing ... this code (outputDocument.Save(sNameLastCombineFile); outputDocument.Close(); inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(sNameLastCombineFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify); 
PDF's have an average size of 12 MB and are 300+

Comment: The system should flush files automatically when you close them. With so many files of that size, you have to make sure your code runs as a 64-bit process as the generated file will be larger than 2 GB and PDFsharp will need more memory than that.

Comment: PDFsharp was not designed to reduce the file size of PDF files. Assuming that the source PDF files are already compressed, the size of the combined file will be about the sum of the source files.