# PDFsharp document outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, pdfsharp

I have a PDF document created using PDFsharp.  This pdf document has 1000 pages. I am trying to save this 1000 pages PDF document into memory stream. It gives out of memory exception while storing the document in stream. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
       var pdf = createPDFSharpDocument(); // some logic that makes the pdfsharp document.
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdf.Save(stream, false);
       //some logic to use the stream that is generated
```

Comment: Not enough information. Not enough code to replicate the problem. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it just text in the pages, or are there embedded images, etc? You could quite easily go out of memory with a 1000 page document, if it isn't merely text-based. You could split it into several documents first, load the separate docs into memory, process and recompile later. I guess I'm curious as to why you require the whole doc in memory at one time. There should be various ways around requiring it all in memory at one time.

Comment: I am creating this pdf, here I am combining various documents into one and storing it to sharepoint

Comment: I hope `createPDFSharpDocument` closes all the files you are importing from.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33609157/162529

Short answer: PDFsharp keeps everything in memory. Do not add too many PDF files in one round.

Make sure your program runs in 64 bit mode to make use of all the memory.

To reduce the memory footprint, add a few PDF files, save the stream, close it, re-open it, add a few PDF files and so forth.
And don't forget to close the PDF files you are importing from.

Comment: Using the official latest version in Nuget (1.32.3057), saving, closing and reopening doesn't lower the memory profile.

Comment: @JamesBirch Only problems that can be replicated with the current version (1.50 RC2 as of now) will be investigated. Don't forget to add `using` for all objects that implement `IDisposible`. 1.50 RC2 is the latest official version.